# In ArangoDB, can we do geo distributed sharding

Tags: replication, distributed, sharding, arangodb

The use case is that we have customers in US, EU and China. Due to legislation, EU customers data should not be stored outside EU, US customers data should not be stored in China. Due to performance, data should be as close to the customer as possible, and should be replicated/redundant as much as possible. So the plan is split the customers data into 3 shards, `customer_us`, `customer_eu`, `customer_cn`, and have 3 data-center, `California`, `Beijing` and `Geneva`, such that:

- `Beijing` holds `customer_cn`
- `California` holds `customer_cn` and `customer_us`
- `Geneva` holds `customer_cn`, `customer_us` and `customer_eu`

Now the whole example is taken from http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Distributed-Sharding.html , but OrientDB has the concept of Class and Inheritance. AFAIK, ArangoDB shards by shard `key`. My question is

1. Can we do the same sharding using ArangoDB shard `key`, and how do we configure sharding and replication as such?
2. If we have associated data, say "invoice", such that each invoice must belong to one and only one customer, can we automatically, somehow, distributed them in the same manner without taking care of shard `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArangoDB currently doesn't offer a datacenter awareness or a zone concept.
Currently only a disconnected setup eventually with replication may get you partially to the point you want to get.

You would create several databases, like db_cn, etc, and [replicate them](https://docs.arangodb.com/Replication/index.html) to the different data centers.
The replication slave will give you a read only copy.

We may see an implementation of this in 2016. Since such a feature is pretty special (and latency to access data from another datacenter may be very high), whats your usecase? Would you like to contact us at hackers at arangodb.com ?

Comment: My use case is, as described in the question, due to https://dome9.com/blog/patriot-act-vs-data-protection-laws-usa-vs-europe/

Answer (score 3):

In ArangoDB you can control by which attributes of your documents the sharding is done for a particular collection, it does not always have to be `_key`. If you have two collections, you can make them shard their documents by the same sharding attribute(s). Furthermore, you can tell both collections to have the same number of shards and to distribute their shards in the same way (see option "distributeShardsLike" in `_create`). This will lead to collocation of related documents.

Unfortunately, at this stage ArangoDB does offer no control as to how the shards are distributed across your datacenters. Therefore we recommand to install one ArangoDB cluster instance on each continent and handle the correct replication of your data across data centers in the application code.

One should also keep in mind that with the current API, in the case of failures, ArangoDB is free to move shards between servers in the cluster and there is no way to configure restrictions for this movement. In the future we plan to address this by making ArangoDB rack- and datacenter-aware and allow a better control over the shard distribution. Then the above recommendation will change.